Is it wrong to have a useless state in the given pushdown automata?
I am a university student. We are learning pushdown-automata. We have a question in textbook as follows
Q )  Obtain a pushdown-automata to accept the language $L = \{ a^n b^n | n >= 1 \}$ by a final state.
My teacher gave me the following pushdown-automata which I also agree is correct

I made the following pushdown-automata

He said my answer is wrong and he was explaining that if I can accept the right language without state q3, it will be wrong to add q3. Also adding a redundant state to pushdown-automata is incorrect.
I am confused, why is it wrong to have an extra redundant state?
I think if they both accept the needed grammer then both are correct.
